# jQuery how to append advanced

Tags: jquery

So my dom generates divs `<div id="test">random text goes here</div>` is it possible to jquery insert a span tag inside of this div like: `<div id="test"><span>random text goes here</span></div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `wrapInner` function like below,

```
$('#test').wrapInner('<span/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`wrapInner()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, check out [`$.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/):

#### Wrapping Element

```
/* Wrap an HTML structure around the content of each matched element */
$("#test").wrapInner("<span>");
```

#### Callback Function

Alternatively, you can use a anonymous function to gain a bit more control:

```
$("#test").wrapInner(function() {
  return '<span class="' + this.id + '" />';
});
```

Which would apply the `id` values as a class name:

```
<div id="test">
  <span class="test">random text goes here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`$.wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) like this

```
$('#test').wrapInner('<span/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want total control over your inner stuff (like you also want to make some modifications in your method) you can use it this way:

```
$("div#test").append(function () {
    //you can refer to the object you are making modifications in as 'this'
    var txt = $(this).text();
    //do your modifications for the 'txt' if needed
    //..
    //finally use return statement to return the value or
    //object you need to the original append function
    //$("<span>") creates a span html element
    return $("<span>").text(txt);
});
```

---

This question has been answered by many guy with wrapInner() method, I just wanted to show you how you how you can make some 'magic" inside the function

Answer (score 0):

As answered by others you can use `wrapInner`. Otherwise you can do it just by using `html` method

```
$('#test').html($('<span>').html($('#test').html()));
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zcg9B/